# Cursor keeps resetting to default unless I set it on MouseMove

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, mouseevent

Have a simple form that has a PictureBox in one location. I want to change the cursor to the Cross cursor when entering that control, and change it back when it leaves.

```
private void Canvas_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Canvas.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    this.Canvas.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

This doesn't work. If I look closely, I can see it quickly change on MouseEnter, but it flips right back to the default cursor. I have to add `"this.Canvas.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;"` to the MouseMove event in order for it to work, but then I can constantly see it flickering back to the default cursor.

What gives? This is the only cursor-related code in my whole application, what would be causing it to reset to the default cursor every time I move the mouse?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am an idiot. Person I am collaborating with on this little app had some cursor code tucked away somewhere else that was causing the problem. Thanks guys.

Comment: Would it be easier to do that in CSS? `canvas { cursor: crosshair }`

Comment: Oh. Please ignore that comment. ::facepalm::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried in a new project from scratch (with just the mouseenter/leave handlers and nothing else) and it works.

Might be something else in your application ?

Comment: Yup, it was... The PictureBox was a custom control that inherited from PictureBox, and the person I was collaborating with had tucked some code away in there because he added a resize handle in the corner. Thanks and sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you set the cursor for the picturebox?

```
yourPictureBox.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the picture box is named "Canvas" so that is in fact what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This is weird. Did you try use `private void  yourPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){ yourPictureBox.Cursor = Cursors.Cross; }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  pictureBox1.MouseHover += new EventHandler(PictureBox1_MouseHover);
}

void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.PictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
}
```

You want to use `MouseHover` event handler.

Comment: Just tried this, the cursor remains an arrow when entering the PictureBox, then changes to the Cross as soon as I stop moving the mouse. Once I start moving again, it changes back to the default cursor, and stays that way even when I stop, unless I leave and re-enter the PictureBox again.

Comment: @AdamWathan post your full code in the question. Maybe there is something missing. An EventHandler maybe...

Comment: Hmmm my that solution is working on my sample project.  In the designer window click on the picturebox and look at the properties.